# How do I produce a É character in the tty login prompt?

Tags: login, password, console, special-characters, unicode-entry

**TL;DR :** How can I produce a É character in the tty login prompt ?

**Long story :** Ok so I was playing with the application "Unity Tweak Tool" to discover some nice features but at some point the whole interface froze and I had to restart my computer the hard way. Now Unity is dead (once I'm logged I just have my desktop icons).

I thought I could maybe reset or reinstall Unity with tty1 terminal but... My password contains É. The problem is that the uppercase key on my keyboard doesn't uppercase the é character in the tty login prompt ("azerty" french keyboard). So basically I'm kinda screwed (I'm writing this from the guest user).

Is there any way to produce a É character with keyboard shortcuts only?

Comment: Did you try right-ALT + Shift + E?

Comment: Also, ALT + 201 works for me.

Comment: For me **Alt Gr** + **R Shift** + **E** = ¢

But yeah **Alt** + **201** works for me ! Thanks a lot !!

Comment: Good to see that it works! Allow me to post the suggestion as an answer, and please mark this as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+[[unicode in decimal using numpad digits]](http://www.ascii-code.com/) works at the console, providing your environment is properly configured to expect UTF-8 (via LOCALE or LANG environment variables). In your case, you should enter <kbd>Alt</kbd> + 201.

Comment: Jos is an old fart too and remembers DOS too (where this was the *only* way of typing these characters)

Comment: I am a much older fart than you, young man. Now get off my lawn.